# Primes of the form $a^2+b^2+4$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it known whether there are infinitely many primes of this form? What about for the more general form $a^2+b^2+k$ with fixed non-zero $k$? Is there any k for which we know the answer?

Edit: It appears this was proven for all k by Linnik using his dispersion method

Comment: So let $k$ be fixed and $a,b$ vary?

Comment: Yes k fixed. Added an edit

Comment: I'd expect this to be true but hard to prove.  For what it's worth, the density of "sums of two squares" is asymptotically $0$  (see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/205862/sums-of-two-squares-positive-lower-density/205866#205866)) so density arguments won't help.  To be sure, I could certainly be wrong.  Maybe try an "easier" question, like $a^2+b^2+c^2+4$.  Since adding a fourth variable makes the problem easy, maybe something can be said about three variables?  For three squares the density is positive, $\frac 56$ I believe, and that ought to be a big help.

Comment: I remember seeing somewhere a claim that this was proved for k=1 recently but can't find the source...

Comment: @lulu It is known that there are infinitely many primes of the form a^2+b^2+c^2+k, for any k. It follows from Legendre and Dirichlet's theorems.

Comment: @DragosIonescu  Thank you, that makes sense.  Positive density is critical for arguments like that.

Comment: When I see this type of questions, I keep wondering if any form other primes in arithmetic progression is known for there are infinitely many primes?

Answer (score -1):

Since we know that every prime of the form $4k+1$ can be written as [$a^2+b^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) , any two consecutive prime with a difference of $4$ will do the trick .

For eg . we note that $13 , 17$ are two such numbers . Since $13 = 3^2+2^2$ , we get $$17 = 3^2+2^2+4$$

If we prove that there are infinite consecutive primes with a gap of $4$ , we can show that there are infinite primes of the form $a^2+b^2+4.$

Comment: Yes, but proving there are infinity many primes with a gap of 4 is a much stronger statement, known to be unsolved. Note that the question I asked is a weaker version of this

Comment: @TheDemonix But we can't, so whilst interesting, that doesn't help. The fact is that no one knows whether there are infinitely many primes of that form.

Comment: @DragosIonescu Agree with you , but I doubt if there could be an elementary proof for your question .

Comment: Note that this is neither necessary nor sufficient to answer the question, so it seems a bit irrelevant.  You could have infinitely many prime gaps of length 4 that all happen to be  located at $4k+3$ primes, and it wouldn’t help one bit.