# About the infinitude of the primes of the form: $x^2+y^2+d$ where $d≥1$ is a positive integer

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

When I read this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_prime about the infinitude of Pythagorean primes. I am asking about the results about the infinitude of the primes of the form: $x^2+y^2+d$ where $d≥1$ is a **fixed** positive integer.

Comment: @DonThousand: But $d$ is fixed and not necessarily a prime.

Comment: @DonThousand: If you fix $d=1$, then the fact is not obvious

Comment: Ah $d$ is fixed, this wasn't obvious to me. I see.

Comment: In 1969, Motohashi, Yoichi, proved that there are infinitely many primes of type $d=1$, in  "On the distribution of prime numbers which are of the form $x^2+y^2+1$, Acta Arith., 16, pp351-363, (1969/1970)".

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Primes of the form $a^2+b^2+4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3493089/318073) - there, it is stated that this was proven for all $d$ by Linnik using his dispersion method.

Comment: It's easy to see that there is an infinity of primes of the form $x^2+y^2+d$. You simply take the primes of the form $p=4n+3$, of which there is an infinity, and you convert them into the form $p=x^2+y^2+d$. Example: $7=1^2+2^2 +3$, $11=1^2 +3^2 +1=2^2 +2^2 +3$, $19=3^2 +3^2 +1=3^2+2^2 +6$, $31=5^2+2^2 +2=3^2+4^2+6$...

Comment: @user25406 But $d$ is **fixed**.

Comment: "Let $P(x, y)=a x^{2}+b x y+c y^{2}+e x+f y+g \in \mathbb{Z}[x, y]$, $ \operatorname{deg} P=2$, $(a, b, c, e, f, g)=1$, $P(x, y)$ be irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x, y],$ represents arbitrarily large odd numbers and depend essentially on two variables. Then the set of prime numbers represented by the polynomial $P(x, y)$ is infinite." $-$ *H. Iwaniec, Primes represented by quadratic polynomials in two variables, Acta Arith. 24 / 1973-1974 (1973-1974), 435-459.*

Comment: @Vepir, $d$ fixed but it would be helpful to know its value (or values).

Comment: @user25406 You seem to be missing the point of the question.  $d$ is fixed and arbitrary.  It doesn’t have a specific value that would be helpful to know.  The goal is to prove the claim for every possible value of $d$.  There is no single value of $d\ne 0$ that should be considered easy.